# Can't open JPG OR PNG after saving it using Node JS (fs and http)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, discord.js

The goal of my code is
**1)** A user will send an image URL
**2)** The bot reads the URL
**3)** The bot saves the image into the "images" folder
**4)** The bot converts the image to tensor using tfjs
**5)** The bot uses COCO-SSD JS as a pre trained model (with the image tensor as a parameter) and prints then sends the result.

Now, my problem is that whenever I try to save the images using their URL, I get back a file that the program nor windows can read!

It worked once, being able to open and use the files
. But now returns files which Windows 10 is incapable of reading .PNG or .JPG files.

Here's my code:

```
    const {Client, MessageAttachment} = require('discord.js');
    const bot = new Client();
    const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
    const ts = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-core');
    require('@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu');
    require('@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl');
    const coco = require('@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");
    const https = require('https');
    const request = require('request');
  
    bot.on('message', gotMessage);

    function gotMessage(msg) {
        if(msg.content === '!object')  {   
            const attachments = (msg.attachments).array();

            const filepath = "./images/" + Date.now() + "J" + ".jpg";
            console.log(filepath);
            const imageurl = attachments[0].url;

            saveImageToDisk(imageurl,filepath)

            const img_buffer = fs.readFileSync(filepath)
            const img = tf.node.decodeImage(img_buffer)

            coco.load().then(model => {
                // detect objects in the image.
                model.detect(img).then(predictions => {
                    console.log('Predictions: ', predictions);
                });
              });
            msg.reply('Enjoy');
            msg.channel.send(attachments[0].url);
        }
    }
    function saveImageToDisk(url,path) {
        var fullUrl = url;
        var localPath = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        var request = https.get(fullUrl,function(response) { 
            console.log(response)
            response.pipe(localPath)
        });
    }
```

P.S: The "J" after `Date.now()` is intended.

Comment: So the object created is of type "file"? Is there even an extension in the files name? 

I'm curious what is returned is really an image file?

Comment: I'm not REALLY sure what it's saving as. But tutorials suggest that just adding the ".PNG" at the end can make it into a PNG. (I should probably start with that, thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i see is your app is totally out of sync - what i mean

you have `saveImageToDisk(imageurl,filepath)` which will write file to disk, but it executes, puts the file write in queue, aaand then you read (not yet saved) file with sync.

I will try to fix it a bit for you to show at least one way of doing this - but you need to think about some synchronization in your code when you plan the flow of the app.

```js
console.log('Authenticating bot...');

const {Client, MessageAttachment} = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const ts = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-core');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl');
const coco = require('@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd');
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const https = require('https');
const request = require('request');

bot.login('BOTTOKEN');

bot.on('ready', readyDiscord);

function readyDiscord() {
    console.log('Authenticated and On!');
}

bot.on('message', gotMessage);

async function gotMessage(msg) {
    if(msg.content === '!object')  {   
        const attachments = (msg.attachments).array();

        const filepath = "./images/" + Date.now() + "J" + ".jpg";
        console.log(filepath);
        const imageurl = attachments[0].url;

        await saveImageToDisk(imageurl,filepath)

        const img_buffer = fs.readFileSync(filepath)
        const img = tf.node.decodeImage(img_buffer)

        coco.load().then(model => {
            // detect objects in the image.
            model.detect(img).then(predictions => {
                console.log('Predictions: ', predictions);
            });
          });
        msg.reply('Enjoy');
        msg.channel.send(attachments[0].url);
    }
}
async function saveImageToDisk(url,path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var fullUrl = url;
    var localPath = fs.createWriteStream(path);
    var request = https.get(fullUrl,function(response) { 
        console.log(response)
        response.pipe(localPath)
        response.on('end', resolve);
    }).on('error', reject);
  });
}
```

That way, before executing code that read not yet filled files, the code ,,will wait'' until the file is written (or error occures) - you of course should try to catch the errors and deal with them.